# How to use Qt QSqlDriver::subscribeToNotification with SQLite3?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, notifications

I'm writing a Qt application where different models can insert/delete/update the same table. When one model changes the database, I would like the other models to be notified of the change, so they can update their views accordingly.

It seems that the best way to monitor inserts, deletes and updates in SQLite is to use `QSqlDriver::subscribeToNotification` and then react to the notification signal. I know the syntax is along the lines of:

```
db.driver()->subscribeToNotification("anEventId");
```

However, I'm not sure what `anEventId` means. Is `anEventId` a constant provided by SQLite or do I code these specific events into SQLite using triggers or something else and then subscribe to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `subscribeToNotification` implementation in the Qt *sqlite* driver relies upon the [sqlite3_update_hook](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html) function of the *sqlite* C API. The Qt driver, however, is not forwarding the operation performed, just the **table name**, and that should be the misterious *anEventId* argument to pass to `subscribeToNotification`. In short, you can listen to events occurring in any table (given it is a [rowid table](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html), but it generally is) passing the table name to the `subscribeToNotification`method. When your slot catches the `notification` signal, though, you only know that an operation occurred in that table, but (sadly) Qt won't tell you which one (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE).

So, given a `QSqlDriver * driver`:

```
driver->subscribeToNotification("mytable1");
driver->subscribeToNotification("mytable2");
driver->subscribeToNotification("mytable3");
```

then in your slot:

```
void MyClass::notificationSlot(const QString &name)
{
    if(name == "mytable1")
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if(name == "mytable2")
    {

    //etc...
```

Comment: From where we have to call `notificationSlot` . Can you guide syntax for it ?